# How to call javascript methods on click function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use slick carousel (https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick) and they have a method `slickNext()` which triggers the next slide in the carousel.

Right now my html file looks like this:

```
<div class="slick-slider">
  <div><%= image_tag "1.jpg"%></div>
  <div><%= image_tag "1.jpg"%></div>
  <div><%= image_tag "1.jpg"%></div>
</div>

<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>


<script type="text/javascript">
$("fa-angle-right").click(function(e) {
    $("fa-angle-right").slickNext();
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.slick-slider').slick({
            dots: true
        });
    (jQuery)});
</script>
```

However this is not working and I can't really figure out why. Thanks

Comment: Also, don't you want the click method to call `$('.slick-slider').slickNext()`?

Comment: I added the dot to fa-angle-right but it still didn't work. But the I'm trying to trigger the next slide while clicking the icon so why would I need to call the action on the slide itself? Sorry but don't know much of javascript

Comment: It's alright, I'm fairly new as well.  You are clicking on the icon, but you want the slider to move on to the next slide.

Comment: So I just add this and delete the whole fa-angle-right script?

Comment: I'll leave an answer assuming how I think it should work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you are pressing a button to try to get the slick slider to move to the next slide.  You need the `.` for line that handles the `click`, and then the `slickNext()` is handled by the slider, so it should be as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".fa-angle-right").click(function(e) { // Added a '.'
    $(".slick-slider").slickNext(); // Switched to '.slick-slider'
});
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure if it's the older version, but currently, you call slick methods like this: $('.slick-slider').slick('slickNext');

Comment: Honestly I never really used slick and just answered this from a generic JQuery/js standpoint and was answering the issues referenced in the question above.

Answer (score 10):

Actually a part of RUS's answer is correct.  It should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.fa-angle-right').click(function() {
    $('.fa-angle-right').slick('slickNext');
});
</script>
```

Comment: is there any callback for this function like calling a function when slide is complete moving.

Comment: I think afterChange is what you need like this.

//On after slide change
$('.your-element').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  console.log("change occurred");
});

See events on the slick website (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Comment: that is the callback for back next even if i click on arrows i need callback only if i call above method pragmatically.

Comment: No if you call the slide change programatically you will need to create your own callback.  Shouldn't be too difficult just initiate a timer to constantly check if the current image has changed, when it has call your event and dispose of the timer.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('.fa-angle-right').slick('slickNext');
```

You have first call the slick object then pass the parameter "slickNext always.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#banner-side-btns .s-prev').click(function(){
    $("#banner-carousel").slick("slickPrev");
});
$('#banner-side-btns .s-prev').click(function(){
    $("#banner-carousel").slick("slickNext");
});
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: I want to mark this as the answer, just because it's what the documentation mentions... but I can't get it to work with this code either

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("fa-angle-right").slick('slickNext');
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `.slick('slickNext')` instead of `.slickNext()` should do the trick:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".fa-angle-right").click(function(e) { 
    $(".slick-slider").slick('slickNext'); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation on how this is an answer to the question. Don't just drop a piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

`fa-angle-right` is a type selector. It will select `<fa-angle-right>` elements.

Your italic element (why are you using an italic element?!) is a member of the **class** `fa-angle-right`, so you need to use [a *class selector*](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#class-html) which starts with a `.` character.

```
$(".fa-angle-right")
```

Answer (score 0):

This selector can't be correct `$("fa-angle-right")` because this means it will search for an **element** called !

I think what you want is the class selector which must start with a dot:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".fa-angle-right").click(function(e) {
    $(".fa-angle-right").slickNext();
});
</script>
```

So jQuery selectors work in a very similar way to CSS selectors :)